# Joining same table multiple times ,resulting double records

Tags: sql, join, duplicates, left-join

I have master table having field like DEPARTURE_CITY,ARRIVAL CITY etc. Another table secondry_details contains city_code and city_name.

I want output like
Departure_city,City_code,Arrival_city,City_code

**Below query returning the exactly twice records,working like cross join**

'''select m.Departure_city,s1.City_code as departure_city_code,m.Arrival_city,s2.Arrival_city_code
from master table m

left join secondry_details1 s1 ON m.Departure_city=s1.city_name

left join secondry_details1 s2 ON m.Arrival_city=s2.city_name'''

please help.

Comment: Shouldn't that `left join secondry_details1 s2 ON m.Departure_city=s2.city_name` be changed into `left join secondry_details1 s2 ON m.Arrival_city=s2.city_name'''`?Also you may want to group that by master table. Please provide an example like there https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: @AdamTokarski, thanks for reminding me, i had posted it wrong. could you try now

Comment: Please provide some small script to create these tables with some minimal amount of inserts. Then we can discuss how change your query to achieve what you want. You could use some db fiddle which are mentioned in link from my previous message.

Comment: @AdamTokarski , here is the scripts                                                                      create table travel_master (departure_city varchar(30),arrival_city varchar(30)) ;insert into travel_master values('London','Chicago');create table secondry_details1  (city_name varchar(30),city_code int) ;insert into  secondry_details1 values('London',110),('Chicago',120);

Comment: What db do you use (mssql, postgres, mysql, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked this query

```sql
select 
    m.departure_city, s1.city_code as departure_city_code,
    m.arrival_city,s2.city_code 
from travel_master m
left join secondry_details1 s1 ON m.departure_city = s1.city_name
left join secondry_details1 s2 ON m.arrival_city = s2.city_name;
```

there: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c7uKuWYYTTwZCfqufBC7tv/0 and it works as expected.